# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato de una columna de texto a Hora (tiempo)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

tengo un problema que es que en Power Bi estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla de SQLServer que tiene una tabla que almacena unos datos como texto (nvarchar) y el problema radica es que debo de convertir unas columnas para calcular un total de horas.
Acá una muestra de los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debo de hacer es sacar horas totales de trabajo y otras más...así que obviamente necesitaré estos datos como formato de hora, ¿como puedo hacerlo?

o si hay alguna manera de modificar esta fórmula para colocar los campos de formato hora?

```
    Hora Salida = IF(
ISBLANK([hora8])=FALSE();[hora8];IF(
ISBLANK([hora7])=FALSE();[hora7];IF(
ISBLANK([hora6])=FALSE();[hora6];IF(
ISBLANK([hora5])=FALSE();[hora5];IF(
ISBLANK([hora4])=FALSE();[hora4];IF(
ISBLANK([hora3])=FALSE();[hora3];IF(
ISBLANK([hora2])=FALSE();[hora2];"No ha registrado")))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar el tipo de dato, selecciona la columna que te interesa modificar. Cuando lo hagas, se te van a habilitar 2 opciones mas en la barra del menu. Selecciona **Herramientas de columnas**. Por ultimo, en donde dice **Tipo de datos** pone tipo Hora.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender: Si paso esos datos a hora en el editor de consultas, la columna la cual mostré el código me generará error, entonces tendría que cambiar el código de la columna, y no se como, esa es la cuestión.

Comment: La solucion que te plantee es para editar en la vista de Datos, no en el editor de consultas puesto que no sabia si eso afectaria o no al resto de tu modelo.

Comment: El problema es que como debo de hacer cálculos con esos registros, en algún momento deberé de transformarlos en formato de hora no?